# Search bar filtering wrong data

Tags: swift

Disparately asking for your assistance
I am trying to filter Table View using search bar but the data I am getting is not in the correct position,
I tried several times to figure it out but without any chance, the result I am getting is only the first row does not matter which Room Number I am typing
I pasted the code below, your assistance is highly appreciated

```
final let urlString = "http://ccm-hotels.com/ccmandroid/api/getteams.php"

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

@IBAction func BackToMenu(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let MainMenu = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainMenu") as! MainMenu
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(MainMenu, animated: true)
}


    var openCaseRoomArray: [String] = []
    var openCaseNameArray: [String] = []



var openCaseRoomArrayF: [String] = []

var inSearchMode = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    searchBar.delegate = self
    searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    openCaseRoomArrayF = openCaseRoomArray

    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please wait\n\n", preferredStyle: .alert)
    let spinnerIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .whiteLarge)
    spinnerIndicator.center = CGPoint(x: 135.0, y: 65.5)
    spinnerIndicator.color = UIColor.black
    spinnerIndicator.startAnimating()
    alertController.view.addSubview(spinnerIndicator)
    self.present(alertController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + 5
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when){
        // your code with delay
        alertController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil);}


    self.downloadJsonWithURL()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func downloadJsonWithURL() {
    let url=URL(string:"http://ccm-hotels.com/ccmandroid/api/getteams.php")
    do {
        let allContactsData = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
        let allContacts = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allContactsData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
        if let arrJSON = allContacts["CurrentOpenCases"] {
            for index in 0...arrJSON.count-1 {
                let aObject = arrJSON[index] as! [String : AnyObject]

                if let Room = aObject["RoomNumber"] as? String {
                    openCaseRoomArray.append(Room)
                }
                if let Name = aObject["GuestName"] as? String {
                    openCaseNameArray.append(Name)
                }

            }
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    catch {

    }
}


func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if inSearchMode {
        return openCaseRoomArrayF.count
    }
    return openCaseRoomArray.count
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell

    if inSearchMode {
        cell.openCaseRoom.text = self.openCaseRoomArrayF[indexPath.row]
        cell.openCaseName.text = self.openCaseNameArray[indexPath.row]

    }else{
    cell.openCaseRoom.text = self.openCaseRoomArray[indexPath.row]
    cell.openCaseName.text = self.openCaseNameArray[indexPath.row]


}
     return cell
```

}

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {   
   let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailViewController") as! DetailViewController


    vc.dopenCaseRoomString = openCaseRoomArray[indexPath.row]
    vc.openCaseNameString = openCaseNameArray[indexPath.row]



    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}


func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchBar.text == nil || searchBar.text == "" {
        inSearchMode = false
        view.endEditing(true)
        tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        inSearchMode = true
        openCaseRoomArrayF = openCaseRoomArray.filter({$0 == searchBar.text})
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Did you debug your solution?

Comment: no output errors

Comment: Can you give example of filtering the wrong data?

Comment: For example, Room 2006 is not matching with its Guest Name
mostly the first record is appearing only after filtering proccess

Comment: What do you search in the search bar? when the wrong data is filtered? for example say you search Room1 and it gives you the wrong data

Comment: I am searching for room 2002 which is belong to Mark, the result is appearing 2002 but for Iwona

Comment: How do you search 2002 which belong to Mark, since you are searching for 2002 , it will give back the result for any room with 2002, you are not mentioning the guestName in search, so if you want to get the name you should mention it in the search

Comment: You are right but 2002 and Mark are in one record  and when searching for it i should receive all related information, sorry i am beginner and maybe i miss understood the process

Comment: What is unique in your single record? you should search on that field

Comment: Room Number is unique and i have done all what i wrote on the Internet but couldn't figure it out

Comment: If room number is unique then there should be one record of room 2002 with only one guest either Iwona or Mark, so if you are getting Iwona it means that Mark doesnot exist

Comment: My JSON is like that:
    {"CurrentOpenCases":[{"id":2,"GuestName":"Iwona","RoomNumber":"1321"},{"id":1,"GuestName":"Mark","RoomNumber":"2002"}
the result I am getting when searching for 2002 is Iwona.
I am sure I have done something wrong in the code but cannot find it
by the way all data were appended correctly in the Table View till I start search

Comment: is your problem solved?

Comment: Not yet, i need to create a class and put rooms and names inside but I don't know how to do it, can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` method you are showing name from `self.openCaseNameArray` while you are updating your search result in `self.openCaseRoomArrayF`. When you are getting the api response you are assigning room and its corresponding name in your two arrays but when you are searching and updating your search result in `self.openCaseRoomArrayF` the index get changed. Now **openCaseNameArray** and **openCaseRoomArray** are in matched index but **openCaseNameArray** and **openCaseRoomArrayF** are not in same matched index. So you will not get the corresponding name in `openCaseNameArray` if you take room from `openCaseRoomArrayF`.

Try to make a Class (e.g Room) and store Room class `object` in a `array`. Search and show from that `array`. No need to maintain to array for this.

Comment: To be honest with you I don't know to do that

Comment: I did that but now I am getting the an error : Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type ''Rooms' and 'String?'
 openCasesFiltered = openCases.filter({$0 == searchBar.text})

Comment: Thank you @Torongo